# how do I scale text on the z axis?

Tags: objects, text-object, scale

Is there any way to scale text on the z axis? It doesn't work for me and I want to use it to make a hole/carved number in a dice with boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Text Properties > Geometry > **Extrude**

[image]

To use Text object in boolean operation you would have to *Convert to Mesh*