# no point, segment, face selection options in edit mode after svg import

Tags: import, extrude, svg

I should preface this by admitting I'm a complete Blender noob.  I have no problem creating basic objects and extruding faces in edit mode.  However, as soon as I import an svg that I want to extrude the faces on my interface completely changes and I no long have the option to select points, segments, and faces to extrude.  (Dis)enabling overlays doesn't seem to make a difference.  What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: SVG are not meshes, they are curves (vectorial), so you won't have the same options as for meshes. To convert a curve to a mesh, select the SVG in Object mode and go in the Object menu (horizontal menu bar) > Convert To > Mesh From Curve

Comment: don't convert to mesh to extrude, use the extrude in the geometry of the text object https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170441/how-do-i-scale-text-on-the-z-axis/170444#170444